# Docker service update all sections of docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration, docker-swarm

We are using CI (Jenkins) to deploy a new version of application on every commit. For every commit, we build a new version of image and run the following command:

```
docker service update --image myimage:1.2.3 MyService_web
```

Service starts serving new version of application which is correct. But, what if we change some sections in `docker-compose.yml` (ex. `volumes` or `networks`) and want it to be reflected in the service when it is updated? Is there a simple way for `docker service update` to update the service based on new content of `docker-compose.yml`? I know that there exist [many options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/#options) for `docker service update` command but they all need to be run manually for every section in compose file.

Comment: You can use docker stack. You can use the same compose file for docker stack and all you have to do is run docker stack deploy command

Comment: Actually, I am using docker stack. I deployed it with `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml MyService`.

Comment: You can run the same command again to update service. docker stack deploy will update all services defined in the compose file.